# Obsolete attribute causes property to be ignored by XmlSerialization

Tags: c#, .net-2.0, xml-serialization, attributes

I'm refactoring some objects that are serialized to XML but need to keep a few properties for backwards compatibility, I've got a method that converts the old object into the new one for me and nulls the obsolete property. I want to use the `Obsolete` attribute to tell other developers not to use this property but it is causing the property to be ignored by the `XmlSerializer`.

Similar Code:

```
[Serializable]
public class MySerializableObject
{
    private MyObject _oldObject;
    private MyObject _anotherOldObject;

    private MyObject _newBetterObject;

    [Obsolete("Use new properties in NewBetterObject to prevent duplication")]
    public MyObject OldObject
    {
      get { return _oldObject; }
      set { _oldObject = value; }
    }

    [Obsolete("Use new properties in NewBetterObject to prevent duplication")]
    public MyObject AnotherOldObject
    {
      get { return _anotherOldObject; }
      set { _anotherOldObject = value; }
    }

    public MyObject NewBetterObject
    {
      get { return _anotherOldObject; }
      set { _anotherOldObject = value; }
    } 
}
```

Any ideas on a workaround? My best solution is to write obsolete in the XML comments...

**Update: I'm using .NET 2.0**

Answer (score 45):

*EDIT*: [After reading a MS Connect article](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=94241&wa=wsignin1.0), it appears that .Net 2.0 has a 'feature' where it makes ObsoleteAttribute equivalent to XmlIgnoreAttribute without any notification in the documentation. So I'm going to revise my answer to say that the only way to have your cake and eat it too in this instance is to follow @Will's advice and [implement serialization manually](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable(VS.80).aspx). This will be your only future proof way of including Obsolete properties in your XML. It is not pretty in .Net 2.0, but .Net 3.0+ can make life easier.

From [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx):

> Objects marked with the Obsolete Attribute no longer serialized
>   In the .NET Framework 3.5 the XmlSerializer class no longer serializes objects that are marked as [Obsolete].

Comment: @Will: it does pose a strange problem seeing as how .Net 2.0 should allow it.

Comment: I'm also using .net2 of which has no mention of this in the same article for the correct version

Comment: I think when we move from .NET 2 we'll drop the backwards compatability anyway so it won't be a problem.

Comment: What a horrible decision to combine the functionality of Obsolete and XmlIgnore. They had two very distinct purposes.

Answer (score 11):

Another workaround is to subscribe to XmlSerializer.UnknownElement, when creating the serializer for the datatype, and then fix old data that way.

http://weblogs.asp.net/psteele/archive/2011/01/31/xml-serialization-and-the-obsolete-attribute.aspx

Maybe consider to have the method for subscribing as a static method on the class for datatype.

```
static void serializer_UnknownElement(object sender, XmlElementEventArgs e)
{
    if( e.Element.Name != "Hobbies")
    {
        return;
    }

    var target = (MyData) e.ObjectBeingDeserialized;
    foreach(XmlElement hobby in e.Element.ChildNodes)
    {
        target.Hobbies.Add(hobby.InnerText);
        target.HobbyData.Add(new Hobby{Name = hobby.InnerText});
    }
}
```

Comment: Great Idea: Unfortunately that won't work for Obsolete Enum members.

Answer (score 4):

I have struggled with this a lot - there is no solution other than doing serialization manually or using another serializer.

However, instead of writing shims for each obsolete property which quickly becomes a pain, you could consider adding an `Obsolete` prefix to property names (e.g. `Foo` becomes `ObsoleteFoo`. This will not generate a compiler warning like the attribute will, but at least it's visible in code.

Comment: Unless all of your code is in one solution, changing the name of the obsolete library function will cause your other program to crash.  If all of your code is in one solution, just delete the obsolete property and fix all the references to use the replacement.

Answer (score 2):

1) WAG:  Try adding the XmlAttributeAttribute to the property; perhaps this will override the ObsoleteAttribute
2) PITA:  Implement IXmlSerializable

Comment: @Carson63000: But #2 does.  Its just a pain in the ass.  If you're looking at doing serialization now, I'd suggest avoiding the xml serializer and go with the DataContractSerializer, NetDataContractSerializer or even xaml serialization, depending on your needs/abilities.  And there are other options, too, like serializing to json or protobuf (our own Marc Gravell runs protobuf.net, btw).  Lots more options nowadays than back in '08

Comment: What does WAG mean? Is it a "wild ass guess"? Your use of acronyms makes the answer confusing to read.

Answer (score 2):

Yes I agree with marking things with the name "Obsolete" we do this with Enum values

```
/// <summary>
/// Determines the swap file location for a cluster.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>This enum contains the original text based values for backwards compatibility with versions previous to "8.1".</remarks>
public enum VMwareClusterSwapFileLocation
{

    /// <summary>
    /// The swap file location is unknown.
    /// </summary>
    Unknown = 0,

    /// <summary>
    /// The swap file is stored in the virtual machine directory.
    /// </summary>
    VmDirectory = 1,

    /// <summary>
    /// The swap file is stored in the datastore specified by the host.
    /// </summary>
    HostLocal = 2,

    /// <summary>
    /// The swap file is stored in the virtual machine directory. This value is obsolete and used for backwards compatibility.
    /// </summary>
    [XmlElement("vmDirectory")]
    ObseleteVmDirectory = 3,

    /// <summary>
    /// The swap file is stored in the datastore specified by the host. This value is obsolete and used for backwards compatibility.
    /// </summary>
    [XmlElement("hostLocal")]
    ObseleteHostLocal = 4,




}
```

Comment: The use of the `XmlElement` tag makes the usage slightly more obvious, but you are still going to cause problems renaming things if this is library code.

Comment: Why? This will work exactly the same except the property will show with Obsolete on.

Answer (score 2):

I recently came across the exact same scenario as you're describing. Doing some digging, I found out that it's possible to override how a given property is serialized with [XmlAttributeOverrides](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributeoverrides?view=netframework-4.8.1), and with this you can tell the serializer to not ignore a given property.

```
var overrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
var attributes = new XmlAttributes { XmlIgnore = false };
overrides.Add(typeof(MyClass), nameof(MyClass.MyObsoleteProperty), attributes);

var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClass), overrides);
```

[Here's a fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/J6b6vU) demonstrating this approach.

This could potentially even be extended to use reflection to find and 'un-ignore' all `Obsolete` properties if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following workaround:

add a method named

```
ShouldSerializeOldObject ()
{
   return true;
}

ShouldSerializeAnotherOldObject ()
{
   return true
}
```

this may override the obsolete Attribute

Comment: by adding a method "ShouldSerialize*" you tell the XmlSerializer if you want the Property to be serialized (normally used in cases where - i don't know - you just want to serialize an int value if it's larger than 5
it MAY work here too

Comment: It didn't work for me... the ShouldSerialize method was only invoked for non obsolete properties. Also note that your properties should be also decorated with DefaultValue(null) for the corresponding ShouldSerialize method to be invoked.

Comment: Did this method actually work for someone? It is marked as answer, but I can't find documentation to support this use (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53b8022e.aspx) and it doesn't work for me.

Comment: it does (or did?) work. See here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53b8022e(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Bluenuance It does not work for members marked as Obsolete. For these members the ShouldSerializeX method is not called.