# serialization and Obsolete

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Obsolete attribute causes property to be ignored by XmlSerialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/331013/obsolete-attribute-causes-property-to-be-ignored-by-xmlserialization)

Obsolete prevents a property from being serialiazed, why did MS do that? Obsolete doesn't necessarily mean I don't need it anymore.  For example, I mark a property as obsolete because I need to tell other programmers to not use it, but still I need it to be serialized.

Is there a way out?

Regards

Comment: The above duplicate also talks about how to work around the issue.

Comment: If the other programmers don't need to use it, why is it there?

Comment: @Babak: as this is about serialization, so data persistancy, it easily could happen that from one day you deside to not support more your API that property, but you must gurantee that you new build also runs with the data saved on clients machines with older versions. I think this is common enough issue.

Comment: yeah, i have entity that i don't want user to have direct access to one of my fields, so i marked it as obsolete, but i were wory about same issue, as i read it long ago for c# 5 or 6...

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own custom attribute, and in the attribute constructor write a log message noting the caller using reflection. Unfortunately the compile time #warning won't work for this.