# .NET - Is it possible to use both XmlAnyElementAttribute and XmlSerializer.UnknownElement event within the same object

Tags: .net, xmlserializer

I have a class in which I had to change te type of a property from a simple `List<string>` to a complex `List<CustomObject>`.

My problem is that for some period of time, I will have people using the old and the new version of the software. Up until now, when I had contract changes, I simply used the `UnknownElement` event to map the old member to the new one since it was *private* files and it works perfectly for backward compatibility but broke the old version since it didn't write the old format back.

But this time, it is a shared file and it made me realise that I missed upward compatibility and that people using the old version will remove the new member. I read about `XmlAnyElementAttribute` to keep unknown elements and have them serialized back to the file. This fixes upward compatibility.

I now have every pieces of the puzzle but I can't find how to have them work together since adding `XmlAnyElementAttribute` seems to end in `UnknownElement` not being triggered.

I also thought of simply reading back the XmlAnyElementAttribute`property once the deserialization is done but this time, it is the`XmlSerializer` that lacks an event for Deserialized.

Here is a sample of both files:
Old format:

```xml
<OptionsSerializable xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <ListeCategories>
    <string>SX00</string>
    <string>SX01</string>
  </ListeCategories>
</OptionsSerializable>
```

New Format:

```xml
<OptionsSerializable xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <ListeCategoriesExt>
    <CategoryInfo Name="SX00" Type="Principal" Persistence="Global">
      <ToolTip>SX00</ToolTip>
      <SearchTerm>SX00</SearchTerm>
    </CategoryInfo>
    <CategoryInfo Name="SX01" Type="Principal" Persistence="Global">
      <ToolTip>SX01</ToolTip>
      <SearchTerm>SX01</SearchTerm>
    </CategoryInfo>
  </ListeCategoriesExt>
</OptionsSerializable>
```

Needed:

```xml
<OptionsSerializable xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <ListeCategories>
    <string>SX00</string>
    <string>SX01</string>
  </ListeCategories>
  <ListeCategoriesExt>
    <CategoryInfo Name="SX00" Type="Principal" Persistence="Global">
      <ToolTip>SX00</ToolTip>
      <SearchTerm>SX00</SearchTerm>
    </CategoryInfo>
    <CategoryInfo Name="SX01" Type="Principal" Persistence="Global">
      <ToolTip>SX01</ToolTip>
      <SearchTerm>SX01</SearchTerm>
    </CategoryInfo>
  </ListeCategoriesExt>
</OptionsSerializable>
```

Comment: Do you still plan to have some logic mapping `ListeCategories` to/from `ListeCategoriesExt` during deserialization/re-serialization?  If so, in the final example why does `ListeCategoriesExt` have more entries than `ListeCategories`?  Why isn't the first entry in `ListeCategoriesExt` not getting written back?

Comment: Simply a bad copy/paste. Thanks for pointing :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.unknownelement?view=netframework-4.8):

> **`XmlSerializer.UnknownElement`** ... Occurs when the XmlSerializer encounters an XML element of unknown type during deserialization.

If your `<ListeCategories>` elements are getting bound to an `[XmlAnyElement]` property, then they aren't of unknown type, and so no event is raised.

Now, if you have some *other* unknown elements besides `<ListeCategories>` (not shown in your question) that you want to post-process using `UnknownElement`, you can do that by restricting the names of elements bound by using [`[XmlAnyElementAttribute(string name)]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlanyelementattribute.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Xml_Serialization_XmlAnyElementAttribute__ctor_System_String_):

> Initializes a new instance of the `XmlAnyElementAttribute` class and specifies the XML element name generated in the XML document.

I.e.:

```
public class OptionsSerializable 
{
    [XmlAnyElement("ListeCategories")]
    public XmlElement [] ListeCategories { get; set; }
```

Now other unknown elements, e.g. `<SomeOtherObsoleteNodeToPostprocess />`, will still raise the event.  Demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TEDmr5).  But you still won't get an event callback for `<ListeCategories>`.

So, what are your options?

Firstly, you could do your postprocessing in the setter for the `XmlElement []` array, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33180709/3744182) to *[Better IXmlSerializable format?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33163580/3744182)*:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName="OptionsSerializable")]
public class OptionsSerializable 
{
    [XmlAnyElement("ListeCategories")]
    public XmlElement [] ListeCategories
    {
        get
        {
            // Convert the ListeCategoriesExt items property to an array of XmlElement
        }
        set
        {
            // Convert array of XmlElement back to ListeCategoriesExt items.
        }
    }
```

The original `UnknownElement` event logic could also be partly preserved by using this:

```
XmlElement[] _unsupported;
[XmlAnyElement()]
 public XmlElement[] Unsupported {
     get {
         return _unsupported;
     }
     set {
         _unsupported = value;
         if ((value.Count > 0)) {
             foreach (element in value) {
                 OnUnknownElementFound(this, new XmlElementEventArgs(){Element=element});
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

However, if the postprocessing is to be done by the `OptionsSerializable` object itself, it makes more sense to think of `ListeCategories` as a deprecated, filtered view of the `ListeCategoriesExt` property.  Here's how I would do it:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName="OptionsSerializable")]
public class OptionsSerializable 
{
    [XmlArray("ListeCategories"), XmlArrayItem("string")]
    public string [] XmlListeCategories
    {
        //Can't use [Obsolete] because doing so will cause XmlSerializer to not serialize the property, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/331038
        get
        {
            // Since it seems <CategoryInfo Name="VerifierCoherence" Type="Principal" Persistence="Global"> should not be written back,
            // you will need to add a .Where clause excluding those CategoryInfo items you don't want to appear in the old list of strings.
            return ListeCategoriesExt?.Select(c => c.Name)?.ToArray();
        }
        set
        {
            // Merge in the deserialization results.  Note this algorithm assumes that there are no duplicate names.
            // Convert array of XmlElement back to ListeCategoriesExt items.
            foreach (var name in value)
            {
                if (ListeCategoriesExt.FindIndex(c => c.Name == name) < 0)
                {
                    ListeCategoriesExt.Add(new CategoryInfo
                                           {
                                               Name = name, Type = "Principal", Persistence = "Global",
                                               ToolTip = name,
                                               SearchTerm = name,
                                           });
                }
            }
        }
    }

    [XmlArray("ListeCategoriesExt"), XmlArrayItem("CategoryInfo")]
    public CategoryInfo [] XmlListeCategoriesExt
    {
        get
        {
            return ListeCategoriesExt?.ToArray();
        }
        set
        {
            // Merge in the deserialization results.  Note this algorithm assumes that there are no duplicate names.
            foreach (var category in value)
            {
                var index = ListeCategoriesExt.FindIndex(c => c.Name == category.Name);
                if (index < 0)
                {
                    ListeCategoriesExt.Add(category);
                }
                else
                {
                    // Overwrite the item added during XmlListeCategories deserialization.
                    ListeCategoriesExt[index] = category;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public List<CategoryInfo> ListeCategoriesExt { get; set; } = new List<CategoryInfo>();
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="CategoryInfo")]
public class CategoryInfo 
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName="ToolTip")]
    public string ToolTip { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="SearchTerm")]
    public string SearchTerm { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="Type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="Persistence")]
    public string Persistence { get; set; }
}
```

Notes:

- As `<ListeCategories>` appears *before* `<ListeCategoriesExt>` in your XML, it is necessary to merge the new items into the previously-deserialized obsolete items in the setter for `XmlListeCategoriesExt`.

  This would not be necessary if you were to set [`XmlArrayAttribute.Order`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlarrayattribute.order?view=netframework-4.8#System_Xml_Serialization_XmlArrayAttribute_Order) for both requiring that `<ListeCategories>` come *last*.
- Because of the necessity for the merge, the deserialization algorithm does not support multiple `CategoryInfo` objects with identical names.

  If you must have identical names in your `CategoryInfo` list, merging of the old and new representations becomes more complex.
- Unfortunately it is not possible to merge the old and new category lists in an `OnDeserialized` event because, annoyingly, [`XmlSerializer` does not support `[OnDeserialized]`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2897175/3744182).

Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Kwwmhm).

Comment: Interesting and complete answer. The only down side to this solution is that I'm forced to have the properties read/write instead of readonly but it wasn't mentioned in the original post ;)